# Function to automate buttons

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

I have to do this code 103 times, but I can't create a function so I don't have to write it for each of the buttons (working with animate-cc + createjs).

```
this.Box1.addEventListener("click", click1.bind(this));

function click1() {
    this.parent.nombres.gotoAndStop(1);
}

this.Box2.addEventListener("click", click2.bind(this));

function click2() {
    this.parent.nombres.gotoAndStop(2);
}

this.Box3.addEventListener("click", click3.bind(this));

function click3() {
    this.parent.nombres.gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

I appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can put that in an `array` and then put it in a `for` or `while` loop.

I had the same problem. My scripting is to rusty so I do not know how to write the script exactly.

```
var buttons:Array = new Array(bnt1,bnt2,bnt3,bnt4,bnt5);
```

But even that can be simplefied.